# Hashing a filepath

Tags: objective-c

I would like to hash a filepath and save a file with the resulting hash value.

What is a lightweight hashing method in objective C and will saving a file with the hash value preserve the file format after extraction?

Answer (score 1):

? hashing is a one-way process.. it is neither a encryption operation nor a compression so it cannot be 'extracted'

- lightweight hashing: e.g. use [NSString hashValue]
- for compression use zip
- and for crpting CommonCrypto

Comment: Hash functions are very much relevant top cryptography. Perhaps you mean "not an encryption"? That would be true.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I meant extraction/decoding a previously serialized NSObject that was saved with the filename equal to a hashvalue. so e.g. root/child/textDoc.txt saved with the hash value of the path, rather than creating the sub folders in the documents directory. If I then deserialize the file saved with the hash value, will the file format, .txt, be preserved. I already know the answer, dont know why I asked :P . Will use the hashValue method. thanks!